# The file in iCloud Drive are not found in a Finder search

Tags: icloud, finder, spotlight

All my files in iCloud Drive are not searchable in Finder. I did the following:

- Remove/Add volumes to Spotlight to re-index.
- Run `sudo mdutil -E /` and `sudo mdutil -i on /` in terminal to do the re-index
- Add the *System Files* in search criteria.

But still can't find my files. All my files physically exist. But are not searchable. I'm running macOS Ventura 13.1 and my home folder is in an external volume. Any idea?

Comment: I would not expect an iCloud file to be found by Spotlight.  Are they supposed to be?

Comment: @MarcWilson My iCloud Drive files are found by Spotlight search and by Finder search.

Comment: What is the state of Spotlight index on your external volume - the one with your home folder? `mdutil -sav` will show state for all volumes.

Comment: @Gilby All are `Indexing enabled`.

Comment: Being more precise about what I said earlier. 1) In Finder: navigate to iCloud Drive (or to my home folder) and search by content - fails to find files in iCloud Drive. Click on This Mac - and the files appear. 2) In Finder: navigate to system disk (my home folder is there) and search by content - finds files in iCloud Drive. 3) Cmd-space search by content finds files in iCloud Drive. 4) Same results for search by name. Is that what you see (except that 2 should be on the top level of the disk with your home folder)?  Certainly iCloud Drive is being indexed, but Finder has unexpected behaviour

Comment: To confuse the above comment. I have two Macs both running macOS 13.2.  Finder on one behaves as described above. On the other Finder search works as expected - i.e. when the search context is iCloud Drive, the files are found.

Comment: @Gilby In my Mac, the files in iCloud Drive are not searchable at all in all scenarios you described. I did reindexing a fews already. Strange problem. By the way, all the files in your iCloud Drive are downloaded?

Comment: Yes, all downloaded.